# Process dumps when starting with gdb Linux

Tags: c, linux, gdb

I have a big piece of code which has some network operations in it and I can't paste it here.

My problem is when I start it with `gdb` it shows seg fault as soon as process starts. But when I run it without gdb, it keeps running and at some random time it seg faults. What may be the reason ? Is there some memory corruption for sure?

Comment: Please add your code to the post. Have you tried to find out at which point the error is raised?

Comment: A possible reason: you are working in a multi threaded application and there is a bad synchronization between your threads, you can debug your problem by using backtrace at first and then maybe use ´sleep´ to delay some instructions, so that you will be sure of who is causing the seg Fault

Comment: Have you tried running the same code in `valgrind`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0):

One likely reason the process immediately crashes inside GDB is that GDB disables address space randomization [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization).

You can re-enable ASLR in gdb like so:

```
(gdb) set disable-randomization off
(gdb) run
```

You can disable ASLR outside of GDB like so:

```
setarch x86_64 -R ./a.out ...
```

Or you can disable ASLR system wide like so:

```
sudo -c "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space"
```

> Is there some memory corruption for sure?

There is a bug somewhere for sure. Whether it's memory corruption or some other bug depends on exactly *how* and *where* the process crashes, and you haven't told us any relevant details.